# Matlab: Drawing Curve and Obtaining Points that are on the Curve

Tags: matlab, draw

I would like to draw an arbitrary curve on Matlab with my mouse, say a heart or pikachu. How exactly can I do that? Also, I would like to obtain data points from that curve such if I use scatter, the data points look like they form the curve I drew. How can I do that?

Comment: If you want to do a point-and-click solution, we can use a `while` loop followed by `ginput`.  However, if you want a click-and-drag solution, you're going to have to use more sophisticated methods: MATLAB GUIDE / GUI construction.  Can you elaborate on your problem further?

Comment: I would go with `ginput` in a `while` loop, afterwards `spline` interpolation. You will have your curve, then choose uniformly spaced points and you have your solution.